# HTMLUnit and Android: JAXP incompability

Tags: android, htmlunit

Trying to connect to "www.google.com" throw a simple HTMLUnit The WebClient class initialization of HTMLUnit failed on incompatibility with android jaxp impl:

```
    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3);

    HtmlPage page1 = null;
    try {
        page1 = webClient.getPage("http://www.google.com/");
    } catch (FailingHttpStatusCodeException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
```

....

09-30 23:05:57.867: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(289): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-30 23:05:57.867: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(289): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mygo/com.mygo.HTMLUnitActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method 'jsxGet_encoding' was not found for encoding property in com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.css.CSSCharsetRule
09-30 23:05:57.867: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(289):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
09-30 23:05:57.867: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(289):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
09-30 23:05:57.867: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(289):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
09-30 23:05:57.867: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(289):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
09-30 23:05:57.867: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(289):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-30 23:05:57.867: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(289):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-30 23:05:57.867: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(289):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-30 23:05:57.867: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(289):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-30 23:05:57.867: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(289):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-30 23:05:57.867: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(289):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-30 23:05:57.867: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(289):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-30 23:05:57.867: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(289):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-30 23:05:57.867: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(289): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method 'jsxGet_encoding' was not found for encoding property in com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.css.CSSCharsetRule
09-30 23:05:57.867: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(289):     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.configuration.ClassConfiguration.addProperty(ClassConfiguration.java:109)
09-30 23:05:57.867: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(289):     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.configuration.JavaScriptConfiguration.parsePropertyElement(JavaScriptConfiguration.java:437)
09-30 23:05:57.867: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(289):     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.configuration.JavaScriptConfiguration.parseClassElement(JavaScriptConfiguration.java:384)
09-30 23:05:57.867: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(289):     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.configuration.JavaScriptConfiguration.buildUsageMap(JavaScriptConfiguration.java:312)
09-30 23:05:57.867: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(289):     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.configuration.JavaScriptConfiguration.(JavaScriptConfiguration.java:147)
09-30 23:05:57.867: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(289):     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.configuration.JavaScriptConfiguration.getInstance(JavaScriptConfiguration.java:237)
09-30 23:05:57.867: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(289):     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.(JavaScriptEngine.java:117)
09-30 23:05:57.867: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(289):     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.init(WebClient.java:215)
09-30 23:05:57.867: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(289):     at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.(WebClient.java:189)
09-30 23:05:57.867: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(289):     at com.mygo.HTMLUnitActivity.onCreate(HTMLUnitActivity.java:22)
09-30 23:05:57.867: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(289):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-30 23:05:57.867: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(289):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)

- Should I downgrade htmlunit ? (I'm using 2.9).
- Any other solution to use htmlunit on Android SDK?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I solved by downgrading to htmlunit 2.8